# How are weights and roots connected? (In the context of the semisimple Lie algebras)

Tags: definition, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems, semisimple-lie-algebras

I am studying representations of complex **semisimple Lie algebras**, their root system, weight spaces etc.

I am a very beginner so this question is about relating key definitions to one another.

**Question 1**: How are the concepts of weights and roots related? Do you have any intuitive way to interpret these? I see that roots "live" in the Lie algebra, while weights "live" in its representation space, but I fail to connect this in a bigger picture.

**My understanding:**

Generally, **roots** live in an Euclidean vector space, they are like generalized eigenvalues, they span the vector space. The **root system** generates hyperplanes in the space and if we make reflections along these hyperplanes, these reflections generate the **Weyl group** of this root system.

If the Euclidean vector space is a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ its cartan subalgebra, the roots of $\mathfrak{g}$ are nonzero elements $\alpha$ such that we can take a nonzero vector $X$ from $\mathfrak{g}$ and any vector $H$ from $\mathfrak{h}$ makes $[X, H] = \alpha(H) X$ true.

**Question 2:** What is the intuition behind this equality? Can I visualize $X$ and $H$ as some vectors and $\alpha$ also as some vector? Then how can we put $H$ "into" $\alpha$, what does $\alpha(H)$ mean?

As for **weights**, they live in the representation space of the $\mathfrak{g}$. Weights are linear functionals such that corresponding weight spaces are nonzero. Again, I am not really sure, how to interpret the weight space definition $V_\lambda = \{v \in V \mid  \forall H \in \mathfrak{h}: H * v = \lambda(H) * v\}$ and the expression $H * v = \lambda(H) * v$.

Thank you very much for any intuition to this.

Comment: The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is itself also a representation, namely the space of the ad-representation. The roots are just the weights of the ad representation. We can also embed them into a Euclidean space in such a way that the inner products reflect structures within the Lie algebra (look up the Killing form).

Comment: I think you may be getting confused by the abstract concept of root systems and the root system of a semisimple Lie algebra. Weights and roots are both a kind of generalised eigenvalue. That is they are elements of $\mathfrak{h}^*$ which sends each $H \in \mathfrak{h}$ to its eigenvalue on their corresponding weight/root space. The fact that the roots form an abstract root system in $\mathfrak{h}^*$ is then a theorem.

Comment: As for the understandable problem that on the one hand, the roots are elements of $\mathfrak h^*$ (so you can plug $H$ into it), and on the other hand, we visualize them as vectors (like arrows) in plain old $\mathbb R^n$, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3312731/96384.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the roots live in the dual space of $\mathfrak h$. In other words, roots are linear maps from $\mathfrak h$ into the field $\Bbbk$ over which you are working. They are the elements $\alpha\in\mathfrak h^*\setminus\{0\}$ such that, for some $X\in\mathfrak g$, $(\forall H\in\mathfrak h):[H,X]=\alpha(H)X$. So, basically the roots are the non-zero eigenvalues of the maps$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathfrak g&\longrightarrow&\mathfrak g\\X&\mapsto&[H,X]\end{array}$$($H\in\mathfrak g$). And the weights have a similar definition, but this time we are working with an arbitrary representation of $\mathfrak g$ (and we don't have the restriction that they cannot be equal to $0$).

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful! One clarifying question: is the $[H, X]$ some "equivalent" of the $H \star v$ in the definition of weights?

Comment: Yes; the natural action of $\mathfrak g$ on itself is the one that I've mentioned in my answer:$$\begin{array}{rccc}\operatorname{ad}(H)\colon&\mathfrak g&\longrightarrow&\mathfrak g\\&X&\mapsto&[H,X].\end{array}$$The weights of this action are the roots of $\mathfrak g$ (together with $0$).